# What is the difference between Sink and Stream in Flutter?

Tags: stream, dart, flutter

The Google I/O 2018 [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RS36gBEp8OI&t=1663s) about Flutter explains how to use Dart streams to manage state in a Flutter application. The speaker talked about using `Sink` as input stream and `Stream` as output stream. What is the difference between `Sink` and `Stream`? I searched the documentation but it doesn't say too much thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A `StreamSink` is a `StreamConsumer`, which means it can take several streams (added by [`addStream`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-async/StreamConsumer/addStream.html)) and processes the events these streams emit.

If it is the `StreamSink` of a `StreamController` then all events from the added streams are emitted by the stream created by the `StreamController`.

This way you can pipe (forward) one or more streams into another one.

Comment: This is not explaining the difference between streams and sink, but instead talking about how to use them.

Comment: How do you explain the difference of something that has nothing in common? They are 2 different things that can be used together, so "what is the difference" doesn't really make sense.

Comment: I think it would be better to explain what each of them are, and what they are used for. when I myself started dart, I had a hard time understanding what a `Sink` was at all.

Comment: So if I don't need to do any processing, I wouldn't need to use a Sink. Am I right?

Comment: A sink is an event consumer. If you want to specify and API that is able to consume a stream, then you express that by exposing an sink property. If you don't need that, then you don't. Actually I have never used a sink myself yet and I wrote quite a bit of Dart already. If found the video inspiring, but still didn't encounter a use case for a sink in my code.

Comment: Said another way: A *sink* is an abstraction over something that you can put data into. It doesn't say what the data is used for. In many cases, you don't need to create a sink, you just pass a value directly to the function needing it, but sometimes you want to generalize. For example, a `StringSink` is an interface implemented both by `StringBuffer` and `HttpResponse` because you can write strings to them both. In the same way, a `StreamSink` is an interface implemented both by `StreamController` and `HttpResponse`, because you can add streams to both.

Answer (score 84):

`Sink` and `Stream` both are parts of the `StreamController`. You add a data to the `StreamController` using `Sink` which can be listened via the `Stream`.

Example:

```dart
final _user = StreamController<User>();
Sink get updateUser => _user.sink;
Stream<User> get user => _user.stream;
```

Usage:

```dart
updateUser.add(yourUserObject); // This will add data to the stream.
```

Whenever a data is added to the stream via sink, it will be emitted which can be listened using the listen method.

```dart
user.listen((user) => print(user));
```

You can perform a various number of actions before the stream is emitted. `transform` method is an example which can be used to transform the input data before it gets emitted.

Comment: I have asked another question about the relationships btw `BehaviorSubject`, `StreamController` and `Sink`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53349073/, can you please have a look? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is there any difference between streamController.sink.add() and streamController.add() ?

Comment: Nothing. Check this answer for more details. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51397263/520961

Answer (score 17):

If you are looking for a very basic definitions on stream and sinks, then refer to this:

**Stream** -  the conveyor belt is called as a stream

**StreamController** - this is what controls the stream

**StreamTransformer** - this is what processes the input data

**StreamBuilder** - it’s a method that takes stream as an input and provides us with a builder which rebuilds every time there is a new value of a stream

**sink** - the property which takes an input

**stream** - the property which gives the output out of the Stream

For more details, [please refer to this article](http://flutterdevs.com/blog/bloc-pattern-in-flutter-part-1/)

Answer (score 1):

Let us take a simple example of SINKS & STREAMS in Flutter. Please Reade the comments

```
       class LoginBloc {
          final _repository = Repository();
          final _loginResponse = BehaviorSubject<bool>();  //---->> a simple Sink
          Stream<bool> get isSuccessful => _loginResponse.stream; //-----> Stream linked with above sink

        /*
       *  Below is an async function which uses Repository class
       *  to hit a login API and gets the result in a variable
       *  isUserLoginSuccessful[true/false]. and then Add the result 
       *  into the sink.
       *  now whenever something is added to the sink, a callback is given to
       *  the stream linked to that Sink, which is managed by the framework itself 
       *  
       */

         Future getLoginResponse() async { 
            bool isUserLoginSuccessful = await _repository.processUserLogin();
            _loginResponse.sink.add(isUserLoginSuccessful);
          }

          dispose() {
            _loginResponse.close();
          }
        }
```

Now, I am using this LoginBloc in Login Screen.

```
     class Login extends StatelessWidget {
      final LoginBloc loginBloc;  // ----> Here is the Object of LoginBloc
      Login(this.loginBloc);

      void _onClickLoginButton() async {
        // Hit login API
        // fetch Login API response data
        loginBloc.getLoginResponse(); //------> here is the function we are using in Login
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return StreamBuilder<bool>(    // ----> You need to use a StreamBuilder Widget on the top Root, or according to the Business logic
          stream: loginBloc.isSuccessful,   // ----> here is the stream which is triggered by Sink which is linked by this stream
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
        // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT AFTER CALLBACK TO STREAM
});
```

i hope this may make your stream & sink concept more clearer.

Comment: what is the difference between _loginResponse.sink.add(isUserLoginSuccessful); and _loginResponse.add(isUserLoginSuccessful); ?

Comment: @gbixahue [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51395729/what-is-the-difference-between-streamcontroller-add-and-streamcontroller-sink) might answer your question.

Comment: Thank you. It get's me point of truth.