# What is the difference between streamController.add() and streamController.sink.add()?

Tags: dart, flutter

There are two ways that i know to add data to streamcontroller, one directly and other by use of a sink. I tried to read docs of Sink but i am not able to understand its concept like piping of data etc.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Nothing. This does the same thing internally.

The real purpose of `.sink` property is to pass it as parameter of other object. Such as :

```
MyClass(
  sink: myController.sink,
)
```

This prevents classes to access to properties they shouldn't be able to.

**But `StreamController` implements `Sink` so what's the point ?**

Well true. But casting `StreamController` to `Sink` is different than creating a `Sink`.

For example, the class that uses `Sink` could very well do the following :

```
StreamSink sink = StreamController();
if (sink is StreamController) { // this is true
    // access StreamController custom methods
}
```

The `sink` field is here to prevent this. It translates into the following :

```
StreamSink sink = StreamController().sink;
if (sink is StreamController) { // false this time
   // never reached
}
```