# Are there any relationships btw `BehaviorSubject` and `Sink`? and `StreamController`?

Tags: dart, flutter

By reading @abin's answer in [What is the difference between Sink and Stream in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50350235), I have understood the relation btw `Sink` and `Stream`. Other than that, What are the relationships btw `BehaviorSubject`, `BehaviorSubject.add`, `StreamController`, `BehaviorSubject.stream` or maybe with `Sink`? I have no idea if there are any relationships btw `BehaviorSubject` and `Sink`. Maybe these two have no relationship at all? In the Google I/O 2018 video, it basically just uses `BehaviorSubject.add` and `BehaviorSubject.stream` for the output. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`StreamController` has a `Stream` and a `Sink`

`BehaviorSubject` is a type of `StreamController` that can remember the last value added to its sink

`BehaviorSubject` is a class from RxDart a member of reactive libraries implemented for Dart language.

`Sink` is where you dump your object into `Stream`.

hope that help you :)