# How to force a function (validation) before switching tabs in flutter?

Tags: forms, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-test

The layout has two tabs, one for input and other for output, with a tabBar to switch tabs.

In input tab there is a form with validation functions that should validate input before switching to output tab as output would show errors if input is invalid.

How can I force validation when user taps the output tab from tabBar to switch? .. this means changing tabs won’t happen unless inputs are valid.

main screen with tabs code:

```
class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ MainScreen createState() => _ MainScreen();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State< MainScreen > {
  Data _data;

  @override
  DefaultTabController build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 1,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          bottom: TabBar(tabs: [
            Tab(text: 'input',
            Tab(text: 'calculations']),
          title: Text("screen title"),
        ),
       body: TabBarView(
         physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
         children: [
              InputTab(
                  data: _data,
                  refreshDataClass: (Data dataUpdated) {_data = dataUpdated;},
                  ),
              CalculationsTab(data: _data),
   
              ]),
         ),
    );
  }
}
```

in the input tab there is a form with input fields

```
@override
  SafeArea build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Scrollbar() ....
```

Comment: add the related code to get better help

Comment: After adding `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` on `TabBarView`, still you are able to swipe Tabs?

Comment: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()  deactivated swiping between tabs, so the user can only tap on tab name in tabBar to switch .. what is needed is to switch (regardless the way of switching between tabs) only if inputs are valid, to avoid unexpected or incorrect results in the output tab

Comment: You can use [Rxdart](https://thomasgazzoni.com/coding/use-rxdart-streams-with-flutter-hooks/) or any statement techniques, which will be triggered or observed, once all the fields are valid on the first tab, else If found any field invalid then can trigger that and listen to that stream on `TabBarView`

Comment: Can you show sample code please

Comment: All that is needed to be triggered is not switching apps or returning to input tab if invalid

Answer (score 1):

If you are not familiar with `Stream` and `Sink` then go through ***[Stream-Sink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52458233/4390987)***

Add the following dependency at `pubspec.yml` and do `flutter pub get`

```
pubspec.yml:
rxdart: ^0.25.0
```

*Create a class like this following*

```
class FormBloc{

StreamController<bool> _isFormStream = BehaviorSubject<bool>.seeded(false);
  Stream<bool> get formStream => _isFormStream.stream;
  Sink<bool> get _updateFormStream => _isFormStream.sink;

void updateFormStatus({bool isFormValid = false}){
    _updateFormStream.add(isFormValid);
  }

void dispose(){
    _isFormStream.close();
  }

}

FormBloc formBloc = FormBloc();
```

*You can use on top of `TabBarView` like this following:*

```
StreamBuilder<bool>(
        stream: formBloc.formStream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return snapshot.hasData
              ? TabBarView(
              physics:snapshot.data? ClampingScrollPhysics(): NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              children: [
                InputTab(
                  data: _data,
                  refreshDataClass: (Data dataUpdated) {_data = dataUpdated;},
                ),
                CalculationsTab(data: _data),

              ])
              : Container(
                );
        })
```

*//I assume that you have some button or click events, on which you must be checking the form validations like this:*

```
onPressed:(){
if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()){
   formBloc.updateFormStatus(isFormValid:true);
}
else {
   formBloc.updateFormStatus(isFormValid:false);
 }
}
```

Comment: no I have no button .. want to make it simpler by removing buttons .. just validate when user tries to switch to output tab

Comment: You need to on validators that using while filling the form. Once validation fails or invalid then can change the value and listener already implemented on top of `TabBarView`